# Вызов javascript функции из обработчика события в angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть таблица, в которую данные записываются с помощью angularjs

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover" 
     ng-controller = "showBooks">
     <tr ng-repeat="book in booklist" >
     <td name={{book.id}} ng-if="book.book_rating==0">
      <input type="button" onclick="all()">
      </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

и есть js код, который что-нибудь делает

```
  function all() {
        alert('Hello');
    }
```

Но почему же этот js код не работает? И возможно ли сделать, чтобы он заработал? Ведь если написать в атрибуте `onclick="alert('Hello');` то все работает нормально.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле все работает!

Проблема заключается в имени функции. При inline обработчиках в разметке в качестве глобальных функций и свойств доступны поля и методы [*document*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document#Properties),

В данном случае это `document.all`:

> Document.all (*не стандартизировано*, *больше не поддерживается, но все еще может работать*)
>   Обеспечивает доступ ко всем элементам с идентификаторами (id). Это нестандартный интерфейс, вместо него рекомендуется использовать метод Document.getElementById().

В [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms537434(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **all** is *no longer supported*. Starting with Internet Explorer 11, use [**getElementById**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms536437(v=vs.85).aspx).

В примере ниже, можно увидеть, что `all`, доступный в inline обработчике - это действительно `document.all`, а так же, что обработчик вполне работает.

Пример:

```js
function myfunc(all) {
  console.log("Hello, i'm document.all: ", all, document.all === all);
}
angular.module('app', []).controller('showBooks', function($scope) {
  $scope.booklist = [{
    id: 1,
    book_rating: 0
  }, {
    id: 2,
    book_rating: 0
  }, {
    id: 3,
    book_rating: 0
  }];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover" ng-app="app" ng-controller="showBooks">
  <tr ng-repeat="book in booklist">
    <td name={{book.id}} ng-if="book.book_rating==0">
      <input type="button" onclick="myfunc(all)" value="all">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

С другой стороны, раз уж используется ангуляр - стоит использовать возможности ангуляра, в данном случае директиву *ng-click*, вместо добавления обработчиков вручную, так как в этом случае теряется доступ к данным хранящимся в скопе.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `onclick` нужно использовать директиву `ng-click`.
А функция `all` должна находиться в `$scope`.

```
$scope.all = function () {
  alert('Hello');
}
```

Если используете синтаксис `controller` as тогда через `this`.

```
this.all = function () {
  alert('Hello');
}
```